# Envio de Form PHP

Tags: php

Estou com um problema ao enviar o form do meu site por PHP. Até segui o exemplo da minha hospedagem, Locaweb, mas o envio não é feito. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<?php

$quebra_linha = "\n";
$emailsender = "email@dominio.com";
$nomeremetente = "Fabrica da Limpeza";
$emaildestinatario = "email@dominio.com";
$assunto = "Contato via Site";
$mensagem = "blabla";

$mensagemHTML = 'teste'.$mensagem.'';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "From: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Return-Patch: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha;

mail ($emaildestinatario, $assunto, $mensagemHTML, $headers , "-r". $emailsender);

?>
```

Comment: O envio do form ou do email não é feito?

Comment: O envio do Email não é feito :S

Comment: Entrou em contato com  a hospedagem, foi comentado algo?

Comment: Eles não dizem nada, porque o código é de minha responsabilidade ¬¬' Mas acredito não haver nada errado com o meu código .

Comment: Tenta assim `if(!mail ($emaildestinatario, $assunto, $mensagemHTML, $headers)){ echo 'erro'; }`

Answer (score 0):

Como suas "variáveis" são constantes, recomendo que você coloque o nome direto no corpo da mensagem e não em outras variáveis.Exemplo:

```
$headers .= "From:email@dominio.com" . \r \n;
```

No lugar de:

```
$headers .= "From: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha;
```

Não sei se é isso, mas pode ser... 
Caso for erro de alguma configuração de servidor, tente forçar um erro ou contatar seus serviços de servidor.